# How to convert a set of Python lists to numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to set the type of a set of arrays to be of the type `np.ndarray` each one. Since I need to do it multiple times, I'm trying a `for` loop, it seems to be correctly converting from `list` to `np.ndarray` when executing the loop, but once it ends, each of the arrays are still of `list` type, this block below helped me to realize that it is happening, but I have no idea why it is happening

So, why is this happening? and how to fix it? Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np

pos = [1,1,1]
vel = [1,1,2]
# vel = np.array([1,1,2])
accel = [1,1,3]

print('\nredefining...')
for elem in [pos,vel,accel]:
    # checks if the array is of the np.ndarray class
    print(type(elem))
    if not isinstance(elem, np.ndarray):
        elem = np.array(elem)
        print(type(elem))
    print('---------------------------')

print('\nafter the redefinition:')

print(type(pos))
print(type(vel))
print(type(accel))
```

output:

```
redefining...
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------

after the redefinition:
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: You didn't redefine pos/vel/accel.  You set `elem` to the converted value and overwrote it each time through the loop.

Comment: This is  basic python `for` behavior.  `for i in alist: i=someting` does not change any of the values in the list.  `[something for i in  alist]` produces a new list with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Tolonen [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749004/how-to-convert-a-set-of-python-lists-to-numpy-arrays#:%7E:text=You%20didn%27t%20redefine%20pos/vel/accel.%20You%20set%20elem%20to%20the%20converted%20value%20and%20overwrote%20it%20each%20time%20through%20the%20loop.)

```py
import numpy as np

pos = [1, 1, 1]
vel = [1, 1, 2]
accel = [1, 1, 3]

arrays = [pos, vel, accel]

for i in range(len(arrays)):
    if not isinstance(arrays[i], np.ndarray):
        arrays[i] = np.array(arrays[i])

# Update the original variables
pos, vel, accel = arrays

print('\nAfter the redefinition:')
print(type(pos))   # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(vel))   # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(accel)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: The issue you're encountering is due to the way Python handles variable assignment and scoping within loops. When you're iterating over the list `[pos, vel, accel]` in the for loop, elem becomes a local reference to each of the list elements (i.e., `pos`, `vel`, `accel`). Modifying elem by assigning it to `np.array(elem)` does not modify the original arrays `pos`, `vel`, `accel` themselves but only changes the local reference elem within the loop.

Comment: Seems a waste of code to set up a container and a loop to further expand it back to variables. Not pythonic IMO.

Comment: This is the more complete answer to the actual problem, thanks, I really wanted to know what was happening. Anyway, as mentioned by @mozway, I think I'm just converting the arrays one by one, it is part of a bigger implementation and I need to save memory by not creating more arrays

Comment: @CosmeticMichu what do you mean by "*not creating more arrays*"? Using a container will not duplicate the objects.

Comment: @mozway when declaring "arrays",  is it just references?

Comment: Yes, those are just references

Comment: A variant without the useless loop with variable: `pos, vel, accel = map(np.asarray, (pos, vel, accel))`

Answer (score 5):

You can't reassign the way you did it. Your `elem` variable is overwritten inside the loop at each step and the original variables remain unchanged.

Simply use:

```
pos = np.array(pos)
vel = np.array(vel)
accel = np.array(accel)
```

Or with `asarray` as suggested by @jared, which avoids copying the array if it is already an array:

```
pos = np.asarray(pos)
vel = np.asarray(vel)
accel = np.asarray(accel)
```

As a one liner:

```
pos, vel, accel = map(np.asarray, (pos, vel, accel))
```

Or if you really want to check the type (which is not needed IMO):

```
def to_numpy(elem):
    return elem if isinstance(elem, np.ndarray) else np.array(elem)

pos = to_numpy(pos)
vel = to_numpy(vel)
accel = to_numpy(accel)
```

Last suggestion, if you have many variables, **use a container**:

```
items = {'pos': pos, 'vel': vel, 'accel': accel}

arrays = {k: elem if isinstance(elem, np.ndarray) else np.array(elem)
          for k, v in items.items()}
```

Comment: Rather than the check, maybe `np.asarray` would be better? Using `np.asarray` means the array would not be copied if it is already a numpy array. I'd have to test it to see which is faster, using `isinstance` or just calling `np.asarray` (I don't know if `np.asarray` checks the type in Python or C).

Comment: @jared I agree, it's better than the check, I just reused OP's code here. I'll add this as note though.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are changing the type of "elem", that takes on the values of the variables in the loop, not the types of variables themselves. You can fix this by fe. doing this:

```
import numpy as np

pos = [1,1,1]
vel = [1,1,2]
# vel = np.array([1,1,2])
accel = [1,1,3]

print(type(pos))
print(type(vel))
print(type(accel))

print('\nredefining...')

pos = np.array(pos)
vel = np.array(vel)
accel = np.array(accel)

print('\nafter the redefinition:')

print(type(pos))
print(type(vel))
print(type(accel))
```